# What's an elegant way to append String elements in a Scala Set?

Tags: scala, set, string-concatenation

I have an immutable Scala `Set[String]` containing a few strings, say `{"a", "b", "c"}`. I want to basically append them into a `String` that looks like `"\"a\",\"b\",\"c\""`. I know I can make a `var resultStr` and use a for-loop to get the result. But since Scala encourages using an immutable *val* over *val* and also has so many operations defined over the set, I was wondering if there was a more elegant way to achieve the result.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to make a String from a scala collection, then you can simply use `mkString(sep)`. Eg,

```
Set("a", "b", "c").mkString(",")
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `map` to surround them with quotes and then `mkString` to join them up with comma as the separator.

```
s.map(x => s""""$x"""").mkString(",")
```

or

```
s.map(x => "\"" + x + "\"").mkString(",")
```

(The treble quote is a Scala way to avoid having to escape anything from within, and the dollar is string interpolation.)

Comment: Thanks. I noticed that there is another overloaded form of _mkString(start, sep, end)_ so i ended up using _mkString("\"", "\",\"", "\"")_